# 403 Forbidden Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I wanted to scrape some data from the website, so I thought to check the response first. and I am getting 403 forbidden error when I am trying to execute the following code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3'}
reg_url = "https://www.g2.com/O"
req = Request(url=reg_url, headers=headers) 
html = urlopen(req).read() 
print(html)
```

can someone help me solve this issue, I tried changing headers but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you must include "Cookie" in the header as well (check chrome devtools to see this value if you just navigate to it)

note that the "Cookie" is likely to expire after some amount of time ... this is a protective measure to protect against scraping their front end(which is basically using their frontend as an API).